# Dirac delta of a non-invertible function with poles in the derivatives

Tags: dirac-delta

Is there a way to define a dirac delta of the following form:

$$\delta(x_0-f(x))$$

where the function $f$ is non-invertible and has poles in its derivatives.

Comment: Maybe for some values of $x_0$ it could make sense but I don't think so in general.

Comment: $\delta(1-\log |x|) = \lim_{n\to \infty} 2n 1_{|1-\log |x| |<1/n}$ doesn't pose much problems